# Чтение полученного значения JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, у меня есть скрипт, в нем метод, который получает response. Строка вида:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SOMETHING</string>
```

Как мне получить из нее только значение `SOMETHING` (true, false, список id)? При том, что это всегда один блок. Остальное не нужно.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagname('string')[0].innerText`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, _**Строка** вида_ - о каком `ocument.getElementsByTagname` может идти речь?

Comment: `/true/.test('<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</string>')`

Comment: Скрипт в браузере или в nodejs?

Comment: @br3t а если это будет не true?

Comment: @andreymal скрипт в MS Dynamics CRM. Она работает в браузере.

Comment: @IvanMaslov, тогда и `test` вернет false: `/true/.test('<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">‌​false</string>')`

Comment: @br3t но мне нужно использовать эту строку потом. Вывести пользователю

Comment: Ну так используйте строку дальше, `test` ее не меняет, он просто показывает, есть ли там `true`

Comment: А лучше дополните вопрос, раз вам не `получить из нее только значение`

Comment: @br3t нужно достать только текст без оболочки этой. И может быть не только true/false, а список айдишников, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```js
var response = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SOMETHING</string>';
var content = response.match(/<string[^>]+>([^<]+)/)[1];
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SOMETHING</string>';
str = str.slice(str.indexOf('/">') + 3, str.indexOf('</string>'));
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вижу, что в ответе у вас приходит XML, можете смело использовать [DOMParser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) :

```
var str = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SOMETHING</string>',
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml"),
    value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].innerHTML;

alert(value);
```